# Problems creating a list of objects using a hierachy of classes. vb.net

Tags: vb.net, class

I would like some help on linking 2 classes in a project I made in vb.net . 
I have 2 classes with 3 properties each.
The first class has to contain the second one, like so:

Class1 that contains these properties: *Name*,*Number* and *Days(as list of Class2)*.

Class2 contains: *Date*, *Check-in* and *Check-Out*.

My problem is that if i use the *Inherits* command, i can use the Class2 properties inside Class1, but they are of the same hierachy as the Class1 Properties and that is not my goal.

I want the object of Class1 to have the [(Date, Check-in and Check-Out) of Class2] parameters inside the *Days* property .

I used these commands to create the objects.

```
dim userList as new List(Of Class1)

userList.Add(New Class1 With{.Name = vName,
                             .Number = vNumber,
                             .Check-In = vCheckin,
                             .Date = vDate,
                             .Check-Out = vCheckout})
```

but when i put it inside a loop that changes the variables for Class2, it creates multiple objects with the same name and number. How can i avoid that and give each independent users the desired days.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a one-to-many relationship like that, you definitely do not want to use inheritance.  You need to instead declare it as a list property, for instance:

```
Public Class User
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Number As Integer
    Public Property Days As New List(Of ScheduledEvent)()
End Class

Public Class ScheduledEvent
    Public Property [Date] As Date
    Public Property CheckIn As Date
    Public Property CheckOut As Date
End Class
```

How you declare the list property can be a little complicated.  I showed you the easiest way.  However, depending on how you plan to use it, you may want to not initialize it to a new object on construction, or it may make more sense to make it an array or some other list-type, or to expose the property as an interface like `IEnumerable(Of User)` or `IList(Of User)`, or to make it a read-only property, etc.

But, ignoring all of those considerations, and just sticking with the most simple example, you could then initialize the object like this:

```
Dim user As New User() With
{
    .Name = "Steven Doggart",
    .Number = 1359668
}
user.Days.Add _
(
    New ScheduledEvent() With 
    { 
        .Date = Date.Today, 
        .CheckIn = Date.Now,
        .CheckOut = Date.Now
    }
)
```

Or, you can inline the list initialization like this:

```
Dim user As New User() With
{
    .Name = "Steven Doggart",
    .Number = 1359668,
    .Days = 
    {
        New ScheduledEvent() With 
        { 
            .Date = Date.Today, 
            .CheckIn = Date.Now,
            .CheckOut = Date.Now
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation, kind sir! :D